# Writing a loop where Sleep(1) makes the whole thing too slow but no Sleep is too fast

Tags: vb.net

I've got the following bit of code:

```
Do
    For ystep = 1 To 40
        For xstep = 1 To 170
            Cursor.Position = New Point(uleftx + (xstep * x), ulefty + (ystep * y))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        Next xstep
    Next ystep
Loop
```

All it does is move the mouse across the screen, skipping a few pixels at a time.  If I run this code without the Sleep command, it lags the whole computer and the mouse is all jerky  with its movement and it's unusable.  With the Sleep(1) command, however, it is very smooth and usable, but I feel that it's too slow.  Ideally I would like this to run at least twice as fast, but hopefully more in the ballpark of 3-4x as fast.  Any ideas on how to speed it up?

Side note: I do know that there is no way to exit the loop.  That's ok, this code is only for me.

Comment: Don't sleep on every iteration, or don't stop on every pixel.

Comment: That said, you may never get the specific effect you want.

Comment: Wow, skipping the sleep every other iteration was basically exactly what I was looking for.  Sped it up quite a bit (you might even say by 2x, what a shocker!).  Thanks a lot!